# Convert SQL to linq in activeRecord

Tags: linq, nhibernate, castle-activerecord

I have a statement SQL

```
SELECT * FROM Messages 
WHERE MessageID IN (SELECT MessagesID FROM Publisher WHERE pubID = 22)
```

in project asp.net using activerecord:

```
from m in ActiveRecordLinq.AsQueryable<Message>()select m
```

this correct with project

but I've written

```
from m in ActiveRecordLinq.AsQueryable<Message>()
where ActiveRecordLinq.AsQueryable<Publisher>().Any(t => t.MessagePublisherSiteKey.MessageID == m.MessageID && t.Publishersiteid == 22)
select m
```

What isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

I found this, but I don't know how good it is. http://www.sqltolinq.com/

Comment: real diff for start activerecord and linq.

Answer (score 0):

This should work but isn't optimal.

```
(From m in ActiveRecordLinq.AsQueryable<Message>()
From t in ActiveRecordLinq.AsQueryable<Publisher>
Where (t.MessagePublisherSiteKey.MessageID == m.MessageID && t.Publishersiteid == 22)
Select m).Distinct();
```

Comment: is it giving you an exception

Comment: statement above is syntax error  "From m in ActiveRecordLinq.AsQueryable<Message>() From t in ActiveRecordLinq.AsQueryable<Publisher>"